# Relationship with webform submission

Tags: 7, webforms, views

I have a view displaying a list of nodes. Each node has a webform submission related, and the sid is stored in one field "field_sid".

I'd like to be able to access the submission data in the node view, using a relationship thanks to the sid field.

Is there a good and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `hook_views_data_alter()`.

```php
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  if (isset($data['webform_submitted_data']['data_numeric'])) {
    if (!isset($data['webform_submitted_data']['data_numeric']['relationship'])) {
      $data['webform_submitted_data']['data_numeric']['relationship'] = array (
        'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
        'base' => 'node',
        'base field' => 'nid',
        'label' => t('Referred node'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you. I tried it but unfortunately I wasn't able to link the "field_sid" from the node to the good submission ID. Can you help me again?